# What is the best small DC motor for making energy?

Tags: electricity

so I am stuck between a rock and a hard place.This is my situation, so I am trying to design a small electric generation unit. So I have tried 6-10 different DC and AC motors and none of them are great for what i want to do. I need something that has very low torque (very easy to spin), but has a reasonable power output.I have tried many ones for small wind power such as

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/231692970602?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2648&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/301628441978?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2648&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

and they are too hard to spin. I am open to as much advice as you guys are willing to give. To sum it up i need a DC motor that is very easy to spin and has reasonable power output. 
If you guys also think there is a stepper motor or a AC motor that will work I  am open for all advice.

Comment: There is no such generator: easy to spin and reasonable power. The mechanical power is converted into electrical, so easy spin, easy power.

Comment: You may be asking for the moon here. The amount of electrical power that needs to be produced sets a limit on the "easiness of spinning" that cannot be circumvented. Free energy is not possible.

Comment: You are asking for the impossible. An easy-to-spin motor will not consume, or produce as a generator, lots of power. It is the opposite end of the spectrum from 'produces lots of torque and uses hardly an power'. Both are impossible. If they were possible, one could be turn the other, and that supply power for the first one, and you'd have perpetual motion, which is impossible. Your best option is a much bigger turbine (fan) to extract more power from the wind.

Comment: [Here's a torque+RPM to watts converter to play with.](http://planetcalc.com/1908/)  You can fiddle with values to see what it will take to produce the power you need.  There is a direct relationship between torque and power.  More power=more torque.  RPM figures into it as well.  Faster means you need less torque for the same power.

Comment: It should be easy to spin when not driving a load. Can you confirm that? It will become harder to spin as you increase the load - that's because it's producing power - or rather, converting the power you're producing.

Comment: Worked example for a different motor here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210207/is-this-a-viable-mini-wind-turbine-setup/210218#210218 and here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/which-of-the-following-motors-best-suit-as-a-wind-generator/177584#177584 - maybe adapt to your motor.

Comment: I'll add that recharging a cellphone (if that's what you are trying to do) will take more energy than you think. A typical cellphone recharge requires >=1W of continuous power, which doesn't sound like much, but will require a solar panel/turbine bigger than "tiny" and more sun/air/water than "almost none."

Answer (score 2):

Power equals torque times rotational velocity. If you want power at low torque, you need high velocity. For brushless motors, this corresponds to a higher KV number; for brushed DC it corresponds to a higher speed at rated voltage.

Obviously to get the power, you need to design your mechanical system to produce the appropriate speed. As there is a limit to how fast a wind turbine can go, you have a limit for the speed or need to gear the turbine up to match the generator.

Generally you'll have to match the desired output power to the same power per unit area of blade, that gives the turbine diameter, which gives the shaft speed (the blade tip rotational speed is around 3 to 5 times of the windspeed - the tan of the angle of attack will gives this value; shaft speed in radians per second will be this speed divided by the turbine radius, shaft power is shaft speed times torque), which you then look for a generator of the correct size and then calculate whether you need gearing or not. The [Danish Wind](http://xn--drmstrre-64ad.dk/wp-content/wind/miller/windpower%20web/en/tour/wres/index.htm) guide is for large turbines, but contains much useful information.

Comment: In normal wind turbines the tip speed is 3-5x the windspeed. Searching "Scoraig Wind" should bring some useful design and construction info for smaller turbines.