# What electric setup do I need to get electricity from a BLDC motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, rectifier, generator

I'm trying to create a small  scale wind turbine for a project. I plan on using a BLDC motor with some blades on it to capture artificially created wind. I'm new to electronics, but I was thinking of buying a 3 phase rectifier and connecting that to the BLDC motor to get a DC output. Do I just simply connect the three wires of my motor to the rectifier? I also don't know what to buy to "capture" that DC output so that I can accurately measure how much electricity it has produced. I was thinking some type of power bank but I don't know one that has two input for my DC current.

Comment: This may help sizing blades, choosing a motor, and predicting what you might get from it. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/which-of-the-following-motors-best-suit-as-a-wind-generator/177584#177584 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210207/is-this-a-viable-mini-wind-turbine-setup/210218#210218

Comment: If you are sure that you have a 3-phase PMDC motor with no internal electronics, you can simply connect it to a 3-phase rectifier. You can evaluate the performance with the wind turbine by loading the rectifier with various resistor loads and measuring DC voltage and current. Charging a battery is considerably more complex. I think there are other questions here that address that.

Comment: Beware of scale -- if you're using a commercial 3-phase rectifier it's probably designed to work at 600V or something else (comparatively) huge, while your BLDC motor (unless it's the size of your head, or bigger) will generate much less voltage.

Comment: Also, if you're using a model airplane BLDC motor, you'll need to spin it quite fast to get much voltage out of it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a model airplane BLDC motor. For school, I'm trying to see if blade angle effects the power output. I don't need any useful voltage, just enough to measure and calculate stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you need is a 3 phase rectifier. If you have access to an oscilloscope, you should use that to measure the output voltage (and ripple). Storing the energy converted by your BLDC motor in a battery is more complicated than rectifying the output, but it may not be necessary. You can use a resistor as a dummy load to simulate charging a battery if that is out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm trying to see if the angle of the blade effects the power output so I need an accurate way to measure the energy output. Maybe having an ammeter in series and measure the current to get the power?