# What DC motor specs for wind turbine science project?

Tags: led, dc-motor, windturbine

I am trying to build a model wind turbine to power an LED for a science project. The motors we have don't seem to work well. I'd like to turn a turbine with a hair blow drier and have that light up an LED.

I'm trying to use a DC motor as a generator. I tried 1.5-3v motors, but they don't seem to produce enough voltage. I have some that are higher voltage, but torque is so high that I can't get them to spin with a blow drier. I found instructions online, but it just says use a DC hobby motor.

What specifications should I look for when ordering a motor?

I ended up finding one that works very well. But I'd love to understand why. It is marked as Rf-330tk-07800

Does anyone know how this differs from a simple 1.5-3V DC motor?

Comment: I edited your question title to be about the specifications and not a particular motor, as asking for component recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Ahem, don't you mean a generator?

Comment: Almost any toy DC Brush motor will light up a LED. In my location, I can get $5 hand-generator emergency flash light. It has a motor/generator.

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210207/is-this-a-viable-mini-wind-turbine-setup/210218#210218 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/which-of-the-following-motors-best-suit-as-a-wind-generator/177584#177584

Comment: @JYelton Thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka I'm trying to use a DC motor as a generator. I tried 1.5-3v motors, but they don't seem to produce enough voltage. I have some that are higher voltage, but torque is so high that I can't get them to spin with a blow drier. I found instructions online, but it just says use a DC hobby motor.

Comment: Will the "motors" spin with the dryer with nothing electrically connected to their terminals? You can use a knife as a spoon but, if you want a spoon, then it's better to say what you want rather than what you might want to use (then explain that you are using a knife as a spoon).

Comment: @Andyaka The 1.5-3V spins well, but only produces about 1/2 a volt. The higher voltage motor wouldn't spin at all. The idea is to create simple demonstration to show how a motor can function as a generator. But I'm looking for the ideal motor for this.

Comment: @BenyominWalters, just a random thought, 1) if you combine 2 or 3 motors in series, 2) Large blade (like the windmill)  and gear train to speed up (BEMF = speed).

Comment: Benyomin, if you connect your motor to a 3 V supply you can watch how quickly it turns. To generate 3 V from that device your "wind" will have to turn its shaft at the same speed. You'll need to pay particular attention to fan design. There may be many available on [Thingiverse](http://thingyverse.com) but don't do random, but learn the effect of number of blades, blade angle, air speed,etc., so that you're not just blindly guessing. That's the "science" bit of your project.

Comment: @Transistor I'm trying to replicate something like this https://www.exploratorium.edu/snacks/light-wind . I recognize that all of the details matter to make it work, so I'm trying to learn more about what would make this work. Thanks.

Comment: So notice that they're using 6 to 12 V motors which should generate 3 V when running at a fraction (1/2 or 1/4) of their rated speed.

Comment: @Transistor Yes. I see that. Other instructions just said "any DC motor". Exploratorium itself says that some motors might not work well, but they don't specify what they used. I'm trying to get a better idea besides trying a bunch to see what works. But, I'm having trouble finding information.

Comment: @Transistor Very rarely do I find instructions for a STEM project that works without some experimentation, but research can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I ended up finding one that works very well. But I'd love to
> understand why. It is marked as Rf-330tk-07800

Those markings match the [Mabuchi Motor designation scheme](https://www.mabuchi-motor.com/product/knowledge/classification/designations.html):-
[image]

So in `RF-330TK-07800` the `R` means round, `F` is precious metal brushes, `33` is the armature diameter and case length (corresponding to ~24 mm case diameter by 21 mm long), `07` is the wire diameter and (most importantly) `800` is the number of turns per armature slot.

[Here's](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mabuchi-Motor-RF-330TK-07800-for-DIY-Robotics-Arduino-Air-Fresheners-/401768164507) an example which includes the 'design voltage' (`D/V`) of 3.5 V, which is the typical operating voltage in the design application:-

[image]

> Does anyone know how this differs from a simple 1.5-3V DC motor?

In comparison to a 'simple' 1.5-3 V DC motor, the main difference is that this one is designed to run at lower speed, which is achieved having many more turns of fine wire on the armature.

When power is applied to a DC motor it initially draws a high current limited only by the winding resistance. This current creates torque which makes the motor speed up. As the armature turns it generates a voltage proportional to rpm, reducing the voltage across the winding resistance which reduces current and torque until it balances the internal torque load (bearing friction, magnetic drag, air resistance etc.) and any external load. With no external load it will continue increasing speed until the generated voltage almost reaches the supply voltage.

When the motor is driven mechanically it generates the same voltage (proportional to rpm), so if it runs at eg. 1000 rpm when powered by 3 V it should also generate 3 V when spun mechanically at 1000 rpm. Having more turns reduces motor speed and increases generated voltage because the current passes through a greater length of wire and so generates more voltage as it crosses the stationary magnetic field.

A standard LED can light up on very low current, but needs between 1.7 V to 3.2 V (depending on color) to do it. To generate this voltage from a small airflow you want a motor that has low friction, low magnetic drag, and low [cogging](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/content/cogging-torque-in-permanent-magnet-motors/), as well as low operating rpm. This could be either a motor designed to run on a voltage close to what you need, or designed for a higher rpm at a proportionally higher voltage.

Your motor is designed for efficient operation in low rpm, low current, low cogging applications such as CD players and air fresheners. This makes it a good choice for your project. Other motors that might be suitable include small higher voltage motors (eg. 24 V) designed for low power applications. For example [this motor](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265038379282?hash=item3db584b912:g:X9wAAOSwOtNgEmUu) only does 1700 rpm at 24 V, so it should generate 3 V at only 200 rpm!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This information is very helpful!