# Diametric opposed magnet 3 phase alternator

Tags: voltage, generator

I’m looking to build my own alternator to test a prototype turbine. I have been informed to build a 3 phase alternator. The magnet is diametrically opposed and will rotate at 30,000 rpm for the initial testing. I’m planning on 3 coils to keep it simple. Maximum theoretical power created by the turbine is 6 hp so the alternator will need the ability to produce 4.5 kilowatts. I can’t find a formula to calculate wire size or number of turns in the coils. Also is there a formula to calculate the amount of heat that will be generated by the alternator

Comment: There is a lot more to designing a synchronous generator than a couple of formulae,

Comment: 30,000 RPM sounds high...?

Comment: @KristoferA I've seen jet engines exceed 100k. (In fact, I had to paint the blades with phosphor so I could measure its in-situ operating temperature on one such jet engine.) If they have an alternator attached, I suppose they would run at the same rate. (The unit I was working on didn't have me investigate that aspect, though.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It’s design speed is low for a turbine. Yes my homemade jet runs about 96,000 rpm. The trouble with coupling a generating device to a turbine running that high in revs is the forces destroy the rotating assembly of the generator. Running a diametrically opposed tube magnet should alleviate this issue and help with balance. Turbine could run much higher but I wish to limit rpm at this stage. All I’m asking is how to calculate wire diameter and the amount of turns required to build a generator as a dynometer to test turbine efficiency

Comment: Add that detail to the question @Ripcrow - don't leave it as a comment cause folk may miss it. If used as a dyno what open circuit output voltage is required and what resistive loads are you planning on using?

Comment: Got a feeling your biggest problem will be keeping the rotor in one piece. You might look at Hugh Piggott's works on DIY wind turbine generators (ironless, axial flux). How well they scale from 1000RPM to 30000 I can't say, but the formulae linking flux, speed, voltage, current, wire dia should still be OK.  Links https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210207/is-this-a-viable-mini-wind-turbine-setup/210218#210218 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/which-of-the-following-motors-best-suit-as-a-wind-generator/177584#177584

Comment: That’s why I want to use a diametrically opposed magnet instead of trying to stick magnets to a rotating assembly.